# How can I prevent the Featherlight lightbox from creating recursive dialogs?

Tags: jquery, css, featherlight.js

I have some photo thumbnails and metadata, and I'm using the Featherlight Lightbox to bring up a larger preview when the thumbnail is clicked.

My preference is for Featherlight reuse the thumbnail's HTML for its preview, so I don't have to render it twice. E.g.,

```
<div id="pv47" class="photo">
  <img class="preview" u="image" src="blah.jpg" data-featherlight="#pv47" />
  <div class="title">Title and year</div>
  <a class="purchase" href="blah.php">Purchase</a>
  <a class="like" href="javascript:makeLike(47);">Like</a>
</div>
```

This works beautifully -- using basic CSS, in thumbnail mode the "purchase" link is hidden and the image is small, and in the Featherlight dialog, the image is larger and the "purchase" link is shown.

The problem is that when Featherlight creates a dialog, it binds *to its own* copy of the `img`. So, if someone is viewing the image in Featherlight and clicks the larger image, another Featherlight dialog is created in front of it, and so on.

How can I prevent Featherlight from binding to its own DOM and creating recursive lightboxes?

I thought about moving the "data-featherlight" element to a parent `div`, but I only want the thumbnail to be clickable, not the title (and certainly not overriding the "like" button's target).

I know I could just render the information twice, once for the thumbnail (with the featherlight-data attribute) and once for the preview (without said attribute), but I was looking for something a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `filter` to do your binding above in the hierarchy:

```
<div data-featherlight data-featherlight-filter=".preview">
  <div id="pv47" class="photo">
    <img class="preview" u="image" src="blah.jpg" data-featherlight-jquery="#pv47" />
    <div class="title">Title and year</div>
    <a class="purchase" href="blah.php">Purchase</a>
    <a class="like" href="javascript:makeLike(47);">Like</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your images are added dynamically, the combination of `data-featherlight` and `data-featherlight-filter` won't work, so either you bind them yourself after adding them dynamically, or you use another solution below.

Alternatively I think you could instead intercept the click inside featherlight:

```
$(document).on('click', '.featherlight [data-featherlight]', function(evt) {
  evt.preventImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Finally, another way would be to specify a `beforeOpen` that would check the given `event` and return `false`, say:

```
$.featherlight.prototype.beforeOpen = function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.closest('.featherlight').length)
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The first solution was perfect!

Comment: Well, actually, the first solution broke the anchors inside the "photo" div... clicking the img launches the lightbox, but clicking anything else within the div just throws an error to the console. Looking into the other solutions...

Comment: Well, the rest can very well depend on how you bind your `like` button. The error on the console should give you a hint.